# How do I Target this <li> element in Bootstrap's Navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following simplified navbar (Bootstrap 3.1):

```
<div id="top-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default center navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header"><!-- button to expand navbar on mobile devices -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Demo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container -->
</div><!--/.navbar -->
```

I have been trying for hours to find the correct CSS selector to style **all** of the `<li>` links containing but I can't figure it out.

Could somebody please provide the correct selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the selector to use in your CSS code, then you could use the following:

```
 .navbar-nav > li:nth-child(1), .navbar-nav > li:nth-child(2) > a { ---your style goes here--- }
```

or you could also use:

```
.navbar-nav > li:nth-of-child(1), .navbar-nav > li:nth-of-child(2) > a { ---your style goes here--- }
```

Comment: I should have clarified my question better. I need to target all of the li elements (i.e. Demo, Purchase, Docs and Support). Removing the nth-of-child selector from your code doesn't work for that situation.

Comment: @garry, try using following way if you have to apply separate style for each link item: `.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(1) > a { ---your style for "demo link" here--- }` `.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(2) > a { ---your style for "purchase link" here--- }` `.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(3) > a { ---your style for "docs link" here--- }` `.navbar-nav > li:nth-child(4) > a { ---your style for "support link" here--- }.`
Else you could do this way, if you have to apply common style for all link items: `.navbar-nav > li > a { ---your common style for all link items goes here--- }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.navbar').find('li:lt(2)')
```

or use [`contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$('.navbar').find("li:contains('Demo')")
$('.navbar').find("li:contains('Purchase')")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#top-navbar .navbar-nav li a:link,
#top-navbar .navbar-nav li a:visited{

  /*Default styles of the links*/

}

#top-navbar .navbar-nav li a:hover{

 /*Hover state styles*/

}
```